# Show List of Posts With Comments Open

Tags: posts, comments

Hello to all the WordPress geeks.

I want to show the list of only those posts which have comments open.

I want to send my users on a page where they can select a post to comment from the list of posts where comments are open and allowed but yet not closed. And if comments are closed it should be removed from the list.

How is that possible? Please help!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this function:

```
get_post('comment_status ->open')
```

checkout the codex:https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

Comment: I have checked out the codex :) and `get_post()` returns a **single** post object not a list. Also the first argument is expected to be one of `int|WP_Post|null`. No offense but AFAIK your code will always return `null`. Care to edit?

Comment: There is no function that gives you a list directly.Get the single and make your own:)